# ComboBox DataTemplate Separator

Tags: wpf, combobox, datatemplate

I'm trying to create a DataTemplate for my class so the ComboBox displays two properties and then a separator. The problem is that I don't want to see a separator once I selected an item.
My current template looks like this:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type j:Person}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nick}" FontSize="14"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"></TextBlock>
            <Separator/>
        </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
```

Another problem is that the Separator is too short, it doesn't span the entire ComboBox width.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stretch the `Separator` please use `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the `ComboBox`. Regarding the hiding of the `Separator` this could help: [Displaying the selected item differently in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466592/displaying-the-selected-item-differently-in-combobox).