# ComboBox with custom item template showing template and not text when selecting value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have created a `ComboBox` with a custom items template like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Clases}" SelectedValue="{Binding Clase}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="0">
   <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Margin="0 2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding CLASE}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.BorrarClaseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" ToolTip="BORRAR CLASE" Grid.Column="1">
               <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete"/>
            </Button>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The `ComboBox` is binding to the `Clase` value in the view model. `Clase` is a variable of type `CLASE_TYPE` which is a class that looks like this:

```
public partial class CLASE_TYPE
{
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public string CLASE { get; set; }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Combo box drop-down items]

The problem comes when I select a value, the selected value is showing in the `ComboBox` like this:

[image: Selected combo box item]

How can I avoid this and only show the value of `CLASE` of the `CLASE_TYPE` class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying the selected item differently in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466592/displaying-the-selected-item-differently-in-combobox)

Comment: See also [WPF: How to customize SelectionBoxItem in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214696/wpf-how-to-customize-selectionboxitem-in-combobox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your button a name and add a trigger to the data template that hides the button by setting its `Visibility` to `Collapsed`, whenever it is selected. The trigger needs to check if there is a parent `ComboBoxItem` or not (`x:Null`), checking `IsSelected` does not work.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid Margin="0 2">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid Grid.Column="0">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding CLASE}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid>
      <Button x:Name="BorrarClaseButton" ToolTip="BORRAR CLASE" Grid.Column="1">
         <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete"/>
      </Button>
   </Grid>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}}" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter TargetName="BorrarClaseButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Alternatively, you could create a style for the button that does the same.

```
<Button ToolTip="BORRAR CLASE" Grid.Column="1">
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}}" Value="{x:Null}">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
   <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete"/>
</Button>
```